# Titanium: require a module inside a commonjs module

Tags: android, ios, module, titanium, commonjs

I've discovered that we can create CommonJS modules instead of native or web ones (take a look at your Titanium folder and search the ti.cloud module). But there is no documentation I can find that explains it...

So, I tried to add my own CommonJS module inside the Titanium folder "commonjs" and imported it to my application using "require". It runs like a charm.

Now, I want to add some other files to my CommonJS module and make modules referencing each other inside the module.

For example in my app I have:

- main.js
- ui

  - CommonView.js

In this structure, main.js is my main module and has a method createCommonView() that tries to require the module CommonView (require('./ui/CommonView')) but the compiler complains that the module is not found.

How do I create a CommonJS module with multiple modules that reference each other?

To be precise, I don't want to copy these modules inside my project. I want to keep them in the Titanium folder so it is available to all projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a blog post from Appcelerator talking about CommonJS modules: http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/12/commonjs-module-guide-for-1-8.html

And here's the guide / documentation from Appcelerator: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium

Right now, all module references are relative to the application root:

- in app.js, require('main');
- in main.js, require('ui/CommonView')
- in CommonView.js, require('ui/SpecificView')

And packaged CommonJS modules (such as ti.cloud, installed in the "modules" directory of your application or Application Support) only support a single JavaScript file.

Hint: I found these guides by just typing "Appcelerator CommonJS" in to Google. I'm not sure what method you used to find the documentation. "require" is also documented extensively in the "Global" object in the Titanium Mobile documentation:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Global

Comment: Thanks but I know all these guides. My question was about using require inside a packaged commonjs module. As you pointed out, it seems that it uses only one javascript file and we can't reference other files in this file. This was the goal of my question ;)

Comment: Correct, right now each CommonJS module can have only one file. But you could have multiple modules referencing each other. I was being thorough in the answer, because your question is rather vague until you get down to the last sentence.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium): *If the path string is not prefixed by a ./, ../, or similar, it is assumed that the module is being referenced relative to the Resources directory.* However in my testing `./` and `../` seems to **not** work as it is relative to `Resources` anyway! WAT?!

Comment: As the path of least resistance, I tend to do everything relative to Resources, regardless of the platform. If you're not able to use relative requires, that's a bug you should report to Appcelerator, with a good short code example and specific platform / Ti Mob SDK -- https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/How+to+Submit+a+Bug+Report